# No Rasterizer module

Tags: python, game-engine

I am trying to go trough a simple Blender tutorial in which I need to use module **Rasterizer**. Unfortunately my Blender has no such module. As far as I know Blender has its own Python so there should be no collision with other

EDIT: Yes, question concerns BGE. As fas as I saw I have none of the modules that should be in Blender: no **bge** for example. I dont think there is need to get the link to the tutorial, as Blender Python console simply states that script failed, and the script is:

```
import Rasterizer
```

or

```
import bge
```

both fail.

EDIT2: I have downloaded a new version of Blender 2.68a. When it starts writes: found bundled python. I have for example **bpy** module but no **bge** module. It seems I have absolutely no Game Engine module. What a pity! :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't import these module from the Python Console, they're only available when the bge is running. Add your script to a python [controller logic brick](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Logic/Controllers).

Comment: Also, I believe 'rasterizer' is an deprecated alias for the 'render' module.

Answer (score 2):

While @Aldrik's answer is correct, it took me a while to figure out how to make it actually happen.

Don't choose `Text/Run script` from the text editor, but choose `Game/Start Game Engine` from the main menu and invoke the controller logic to which you assigned the script.

If you want to run the script at Game Engine startup, use an `AlwaysSensor` and connect it to a Python controller. At the Python controller choose `Script` and select the Python file which you have opened in the text editor.